# Why is href not working on iOS whilst it works fine on any other devices including Mac?

Tags: html, ios, reactjs, hyperlink, href

as per the title it looks like href looks fine anywhere but on iOS devices.
The funny thing is that i do have href in the navbar and these ones work fine on iOS too but all the others don't.

This is the website if needed: http://www.fncfranzese.com/

These are the href working anywhere, even on iOs:

```
<ul className={`header nav-bar nav-list ${menuActive}`} onClick={this.toggleMenu}> 
  <li><a href="#hero" data-after="Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#services" data-after="Service">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#skills" data-after="Skills">Skills</a></li>
  <li><a href="#projects" data-after="Projects">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" data-after="About">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" data-after="Contact">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
```

and these are the once not working only on iOS:

```
<a href="#contact" type="button" className="cta_hero">REQUEST A QUOTE </a>

<div className="social-icon">
  <div className="social-item">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ffkekko" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src= {require("../img/iconFacebook.png")} alt="facebook-icon"/></a>
  </div>
  <div className="social-item">
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ff_franz/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src={require("../img/iconInstagram.png")} alt="instagram-icon"/></a>
  </div>
  <div className="social-item">
    <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=393927839583" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src={require("../img/iconWhatsapp.png")} alt="whatsapp-icon"/></a>
  </div>
  <div className="social-item">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/francesco-franzese-7a7243108/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src={require("../img/iconLinkedin.png")} alt="linkedin-icon"/></a>
   </div>
 </div>

<div className="contact-info" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="1" data-aos-once="true" data-aos-offset="15">
  <h1>Email</h1>
  <h2><a href="mailto:fnc.franzese@gmail.com">fnc.franzese1@gmail.com</a></h2>
</div>
```

I tried what the web suggests which means adding / before # where applicable but this doesn't work either.

If any of you has any idea of what is happening i would very much appreciate hear from you.
Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

This issue is sorted. I had an ::after as fixed instead of absolute that was covering the whole document not allowing to click buttons.